# Ruby settings in Intellij idea

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

this is probably v obvious, but I can not find where the ruby interpeter path - as well as whatever other ruby settings are available - in the Intellij Project Settings, compiler, plugins, etc.

I do have the ruby plugin installed with the latest version and am using intellij 12.0.4 ultimate.

thanks for the (probably v easy) advice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA all the SDKs can be configured in `File` | `Project Structure` | [SDKs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/sdks.html).

Comment: I can't get this to work using [`chruby` and `ruby-install`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) on Mac with IntelliJ 2017.1 EAP. Anytime I try to add a local Ruby SDK it just seems like to close the dialog with no error message or anything.