# Intellij IDEA Rails configure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I have created a rails project in Intellij IDEA, but when I try to run the project, I get the error: "No rails found in SDK". When I create a project that I just can not choose the version of rails from the list, but the rails have on my system, and if I write "rails -v" in the terminal, I got an answer: Rails 4.2.1.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I belive your project can't find the path of rails.

Comment: And where I can set it?

Comment: Have a look on this question also make sure you have ruby plug in installed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733905/ruby-settings-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 4):

Open `Preferences` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Ruby SDK & Gems` and choose required ruby version from list.

Or open `Run/Debug Configuration` editor and select Ruby SDK from `Ruby SDK (Use other SDK)` list.

Comment: I have only RVM: Ruby-2.2.1 in Run/Debug Configuration, and I haven't Ruby SDK & Gems in Languages & Frameworks

Comment: [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-ruby-sdk.html) is official documentation which should help to find Ruby SDK settings and configure them.

Comment: Changing the `Run/Debug Configuration` is what fixed it for me. Not sure why the other options were not working for my Ruby 2.2.4/Rails 4.2.6. The do for my earlier version: ruby 2.0.0-p247/rails 4.0.0